# Using pandas to read csv file and place NaN values in columns with exponential notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some temperature data and some of the columns have temperatures that are incorrect and read very large values such as "3.40282E+38".  For some reason when I use this code it is deleting the columns with the scientific notation.  How can I set up this code to keep the column with scientific notation?  Additionally how can I set it up to place NaN values when there is scientific notation?

```
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", index_col="DateTime", parse_dates=True, na_values='Null', keep_default_na=False)
    df = df.resample('1min').mean()
    df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="1min"))
    df.to_csv("output.csv", index=True, index_label="DateTime", na_rep='NaN')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without an example, but you could try this to deal with the problem outside of `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., dtype='object')  # reads data as string
df['temperature'] = pd.to_numeric(df['temperature'], errors='coerce')
```

Because of `'coerce'` the conversion will not fail, but strings that could not be converted are replaced with null values.